# Evaluate the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \ln(1-e^{-x})e^{-ax}x^bdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Evaluate the integral
> $$\int_0^\infty \ln(1-e^{-x})e^{-ax}x^bdx, \quad a,b>0.$$

I'm trying to use substitution $t=1-e^{-x}$ and integration by parts. Also I've tried with Gamma function in parts. But I don't get anywhere. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: welcome to MSE, why do you believe it has a closed form?

Comment: Well, it does not need to have closed form, but it converges. How can I find approximation of it?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a closed-form solution for nonnegative integers $b$, in terms of the gamma and polygamma functions, that uses differentiating under the integral sign twice.

First consider the case $b = 0$. Substituting $u := e^{-x}, du = -e^{-x} \,dx$, transforms the integral to
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-a x} \log(1 - e^{-x}) \,dx = \int_0^1 u^{a - 1} \log(1 - u) \,du .$$
To evaluate this integral, we differentiate under the integral sign. Define
$$I(t) := \int_0^1 u^{a - 1} (1 - u)^t \,du ,$$
so that
$$I'(t) := \int_0^1 u^{a - 1} (1 - u)^t \log(1 - u) \,du,$$ and in particular so that the desired integral is $I'(0)$. The usual definition of the beta function and the formula for expressing the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), $\mathrm{B}$, in terms of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\Gamma$, gives
$$I(t) = \mathrm{B}(a, t + 1) = \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(t + 1)}{\Gamma(a + t + 1)} .$$
Differentiating with respect to $t$ gives
$$(\psi(t + 1) - \psi(a + t + 1)) \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(t + 1)}{\Gamma(a + t + 1)} ,$$
where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function),
and evaluating at $t = 0$ yields
$$\phantom{(ast)} \qquad \int_0^\infty e^{-a x} \log(1 - e^{-x}) \,dx = I'(0) = - \frac{\gamma + \psi(1 + a)}{a} , \qquad (\ast)$$
where $\gamma := -\psi(1)$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). For positive integers $a$ this integral is just $$-\frac{H_a}{a} ,$$ where $H_a := 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \cdots \frac1a$ is the $a$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).)

---

With $(\ast)$ in hand we now generalize to the case of a nonnegative integer $b$: Differentiating $(\ast)$ $b$ times with respect to $a$ yields $$\boxed{\int_0^\infty x^b e^{-a x} \log(1 - e^{-x}) \,dx = \frac{b!}{a^{b + 1}} \left(-\gamma - \sum_{k = 0}^b \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} a^k \psi^{(k)}(1 + a)\right)} ,$$
where $\psi^{(m)}$ is the [polygamma function of order $m$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

For example, for $b = 1$,
$$\int_0^\infty x e^{-a x} \log(1 - e^{-x}) \,dx = -\frac{\gamma + \psi(1 + a)}{a^2} + \frac{\psi^{(1)}(1 + a)}{a},$$ which for positive integers $a$ simplifies to
$$
\int_0^\infty x e^{-a x} \log(1 - e^{-x}) \,dx = -\frac{H_a}{a^2} + \frac1a\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \sum_{k = 1}^a \frac{1}{k^2}\right) .$$
I didn't compute them, but analogous formulae for positive integers $a$ should also exist for integers $b > 1$.

Computing using the asymptotics of the digamma function gives that for fixed $b$, as $a \to \infty$, $$\int_0^\infty x^b e^{-a x} \log(1 - e^{-x}) \,dx = b!\left(-\log a + (H_b - \gamma) - \frac{b + 1}{2 a} + R(a)\right) ,$$
where the remainder satisfies $R(a) \in O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

Using the power series expansion of the natural logarithm yields;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(1-e^{-x})e^{-ax}x^bdx=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^be^{-(n+a)x}dx$$

Applying the substitution $u=(n+a)x$ gives us;

$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\cdot (n+a)^{b+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^be^{-u}du$$

$$=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(b+1)}{n\cdot (n+a)^{b+1}}$$