# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+a)^b}$

Tags: summation, power-series, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am looking for ways to simplify the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+a)^b}, \quad a\in\mathbb{R}^+,  b\in\mathbb{N}.$$
The first thought I had approaching this was to use Hurwitz and/or Zeta function. How should I go about evaluating this sum? (Mathematica doesn't have any simplification, but I need at least approximative form in tearms of $a$ and $b$ for simulations).

Comment: You should have linked this to [your prior post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4879869) (the answer by Travis Willse is all you can get).